# Is it possible to have a child Div remove portion of parent div's border?

Tags: css

Using just CSS is it possible to have a child div border "override" or "remove" a portion of its parent's border? Essentially I'd like to have a border but not on the outside of specific rows, and I'd like to do so without rearranging the DOM structure.

Note that the `innerNoBorder` `div` does not have a background color.

Example of what I have (which does not work)--

Html:

```
<div class="outerBorder">
    <div class="inner">hello</div>
    <div class="innerNoBorder">world</div> <!--have this remove border / override outerBorder -->
    <div class="inner">!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outerBorder {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.innerNoBorder {
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
}
```

JSFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorchasewhite/bc6uLmhx/).

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bc6uLmhx/3/?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The border property isn't inherit from the parent, so your try won't work... but you already figured that out.

You can overlap the parent div though by using a negative margin on the child. Do note that you'll need to give the child a background-color to make it functional.

```
.innerNoBorder {
    background: yellow;
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bc6uLmhx/1/)

## Alternativ

Same method, but than with a white border:

```
.innerNoBorder {
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-width: 0 2px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bc6uLmhx/4/)

Comment: Not a bad solution, unfortunately my child div _does not_ have a background. I'm thinking maybe I could make outerBorder have no left border, then with innerBorder use the negative margin technique to place a border such that it looks like it were in line with the outer div. Thanks!

Comment: @TaylorCWhite, look at the alternative code I gave... That one uses the border instead of the background

Comment: That still has the problem of "a" border being there. Therefore that solution would not work for something that say had an image as a background behind the div. It's better though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `box-shadow`:

```
.innerNoBorder {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/bc6uLmhx/5/

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

Can you not just set the .outBorder to have no left border?

```
.outerBorder {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
```

Or you could position the .innerNoBorder div over the left side of its parent, something like this:

```
.innerNoBorder {
margin-left: -2px;
border-left: 2px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using pseudo elements:

HTML:

```
<div class="outerBorder">
    <div class="inner">hello</div>
    <div class="innerNoBorder">world</div>
    <!--have this remove border / override outerBorder -->
    <div class="inner">!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outerBorder {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.innerNoBorder {
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
    position:relative;
}
.innerNoBorder:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    left: -2px;
    bottom: -50%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    z-index: 45478;
    content:"";
}
```

To adjust the height of "no-border" area, just adjust `top` and `bottom` values of the `:after` pseudo element

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/bc6uLmhx/7/